# How to retrieve the sibling node's value in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm trying to do is to return the value of the key named `class` of the node named `m1` with a sibling named `name`

---

Here's what my database looked like

[image]

---

Here's what my code looked like

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medicines");
        final Query userQuery = rootRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(textView.getText().toString());

        userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String key = child.getKey().toString();
                    String value = child.getValue().toString();

                    txt1.setText(myParentNode);

                    DatabaseReference childRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(myParentNode);
                childRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String class_ = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();         txt2.setText(class_);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
            }
```

However it just gave me error T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medicines");
    final Query userQuery = rootRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(textView.getText().toString());

    userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String keys=datas.getKey();
   String class=datas.child("class").getValue().toString();
   String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
  }
 }
    @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
  });
```

the datasnasphot is `medicines` then the query is `orderByChild("name").equalTo(textView.getText().toString());` equal to the value that is in the `textView`.

`String keys=datas.getKey();` this will get you the key can be `m1` or `m2` or `m3` depending on the text that you retrieve from the textview.

Then the other two will retrieve the `name` and the `class` from the database that are under a specific key.

Comment: Dude i can't use the method `child()` inside the for loop

Comment: and why cant you use it? Im using valueventlistener here also not childeventlistener (but it should not matter regarding method `child()`)

Comment: lol I think i need glasses. however it worked just as i want it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a class called Medicine(If you don't already have one) and make it have two String variables `name` and `class` and create a constructor, getter and setter methods then use this method:

```
public String getClassOfMedicineById(String id){
    final String medicineClass = "";
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("medicine-handbook").child("Medicines")
            .child(id)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Medicine medicine = dataSnapshot.getValue(Medicine.class);
                    medicineClass = medicine.get_class();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    return medicineClass;
}
```

And then call it like:
`getClassOfMedicineById("m1");`
Oh and don't call your class getter method `getClass()`. I think there's a method in the `Object` class so it might interfere or something.